# How to get top 500 results of an array in angular?

Tags: angular, http, operators

I have this function:

```
getAllBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
 return this.http.get<Book[]>(url);
}
```

if the response has more than 500 results, I only need to get the top 500 results. How can I do that?

Comment: Honestly, for this, if I had control I'd try to handle it on the server.  No need to transport data back and forth that you don't need.

Comment: @JeffryHouser yeah, I tried, but the server side programmer just give me this data, I have to process it myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
getAllBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
        return this.http.get<Book[]>(url).pipe(
            map((books: Book[]) => {
                if (books.length > 500) {
                    return books.slice(0, 500);
                }
                return books;
            })
        );
    }
```

You need to splice your array if you have more than 500 books.

Comment: I checked, it's ```slice```, not ```splice```

Comment: `splice` will simply alter the original array, whereas `slice` will not, so yes, `slice` would be a better option here.

Answer (score 1):

Splice the array in the component:

```
sampleArray = [1,2,....];
sampleArray.splice(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let item of items| slice:0:500"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: in my opinion the best answer, in context of angular.